# macOS Mojaveでのspresenseローダーについて

Tags: spresense

現在、spresense arduino library をインストールしています。公式ページのとおり進めていき、 Spresense firmware v1.1.0をダウンロード、ドラッグアンドドロップしましたがここから進みません。
わかる方教えてください。

気になるのは公式ページにあるサポートしているプラットフォームが Mac OSX 10.12 Sierra になっていること
また、presenseローダーダウンロードページでダウンロードしたファイルがzip ファイルではないことです。

Answer (score 2):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答させていただきます。

ダウンロードしたファイルが解凍されていることが、今回の原因となります。
Mac OSにインストールされている”Safari”ブラウザにおけるzipファイルの自動解凍機能を、無効にすることで、手順通りにインストールができます。

**”Safari”で、Zipファイルの自動解凍機能を無効にする方法**

1. Safariブラウザの“環境設定”を開いてください
2. “一般”タブを選択してください
3. “ダウンロード後、安全なファイルを開く”というチェックボックスのチェックを外してください

この度はドキュメントの不備により、ご不便をおかけしてしまい申し訳ございません。
今後ともSpresenseをどうぞよろしくお願いします。